# how to do Transpose function in pandas Data Frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to python so please help me.

I have a Data Frame which have

df

```
        id    status     emailaddress  ownername   Key   
        a     pending    a.gmail.com   as          1
        a     pending     a.gmail.com   as         2
        a     submitted   a.gmail.com   as         3
        a     submitted   a.gmail.com   as         4
        b     pending    b.gmail.com    bs         1
        b     pending     b.gmail.com   bs         2
        b     pending     b.gmail.com   bs         3
        b     pending     b.gmail.com   bs         4
        b     pending    b.gmail.com    bs         1
        c     submitted   c.gmail.com   bs         1
        c     submitted   c.gmail.com   bs         3
        c     submitted   c.gmail.com   bs         4
```

I want to calculate the count of Key column based on status for each id.

Also if the status any one status = pending then overall status of that user will be pending in the summary table.

Total Key = count (Key) where status(pending)

CompletedKey = count (Key) where status(submitted)

Expected df_summary

```
        id    status     emailaddress  ownername   TotalKey   CompletedKey  RemainingKey   
        a      pending    a.gmail.com   as         4           2              2
        b      pending    b.gmail.com   bs         5           0              4
        c      submitted  c.gmail.com   cs         3           3              0
```

My code

```
    dfResponse = df.groupby(['id','ownername','status','emailaddress'])['Key'].count().reset_index(name="TotalKey")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `agg` to compute counters and merge with you original dataframe. To keep the right status, create a ordered categorical dtype to ensure `pending` status appears first when sorting values.

```
>>> df.astype({'status': pd.CategoricalDtype(['pending', 'submitted'], ordered=True)}) \
      .merge(df.groupby('id')
               .agg(TotalKey=('Key', 'count'),
                    CompletedKey=('status', lambda x: sum(x == 'submitted')), 
                    RemainingKey=('status', lambda x: sum(x == 'pending'))),
             on='id') \
      .sort_values('status') \
      .drop_duplicates('id') \
      .drop(columns='Key')


  id     status emailaddress ownername  TotalKey  CompletedKey  RemainingKey
0  a    pending  a.gmail.com        as         4             2             2
4  b    pending  b.gmail.com        bs         5             0             5
9  c  submitted  c.gmail.com        bs         3             3             0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `.groupby` (to determine count of each pending/submitted group) + `.pivot_table` (to reshape/sum the dataframe):

```py
x = df.groupby(["id", "status"], as_index=False).agg(
    {
        "status": "first",
        "emailaddress": "first",
        "ownername": "first",
        "Key": "count",
    }
)
x = x.pivot_table(
    index=["id", "emailaddress", "ownername", "status"],
    columns="status",
    aggfunc="sum",
)
x.columns = x.columns.map("_".join)
x = (
    x.rename(
        columns={"Key_pending": "RemainingKey", "Key_submitted": "CompletedKey"}
    )
    .fillna(0)
    .astype(int)
)
x["TotalKey"] = x.sum(1)
print(x.reset_index().sort_values(["id", "status"]).drop_duplicates("id"))
```

Prints:

```
  id emailaddress ownername     status  RemainingKey  CompletedKey  TotalKey
0  a  a.gmail.com        as    pending             2             0         2
2  b  b.gmail.com        bs    pending             5             0         5
3  c  c.gmail.com        bs  submitted             0             3         3
```

Comment: @Ben.T Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `assign` to create Boolean columns for the different Key columns you want to do, then you can use `sum` after the `groupby`. for the status column, keep `where` pending and use `first` after the `groupby` to get the value pending when at least one is in the group, then `fillna` the missing status by submitted - because if None, then only submitted for this group.

```
dfResponse = (
    df.assign(
        TotalKey=True, 
        CompletedKey=lambda x: x['status'].eq('submitted'),
        RemainingKey=lambda x: ~x['CompletedKey'], # assuming it is either submitted or pending
        status=lambda x: x['status'].where(x['RemainingKey'])) # keep only the pending values
      .groupby(['id','ownername','emailaddress']) # remove status from groupby
      .agg({'status':'first', # get pending if any pending in the group
            'TotalKey':sum, # sum because these columns are boolean
            'CompletedKey':sum,
            'RemainingKey':sum})
      .fillna({'status':'submitted'}) # fill missing status when no pending
      .reset_index()
)

print(dfResponse)
  id ownername emailaddress     status  TotalKey  CompletedKey  RemainingKey
0  a        as  a.gmail.com    pending         4             2             2
1  b        bs  b.gmail.com    pending         5             0             5
2  c        bs  c.gmail.com  submitted         3             3             0
```

Comment: You can simplify `assign` and `agg` in one `agg` operation, no?

Comment: @Corralien yep I agree, I went this way first as I did not see the requirements for the status column, and using `assign` was a way to do `groupby.sum` directly on all the Key columns. Once added the status column, it is not the best anymore..